# non homogeneous heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the non homogeneous heat equation :

let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\Delta u = f(x,t)$ , $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,t\in\mathbb{R}$

$u(x,0)=0$

so can someone tell me how to verify that the solution of this equation is given by :

$u(x,t)=\int_0^t(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\phi_n(x-y,t-s)f(y,s)dy)ds$

where $\phi_n$ is the fundamentale solution of the homogeneous heat equation.

thank you very much.

Comment: try with $f(x,t) = e^{i r x +i \omega t}$ you'll see if it gives the correct result

Comment: HINT: Look for the keywords "Duhamel's formula for the heat equation".

Answer (score 0):

See Evans PDE book, Theorem 2, p. 50. or see page 18 of [PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c2f6/6e2ace9152bd6e2d8b5fa879c661531b77a7.pdf).

Comment: Link is broken.